# c# Replace string with does contains unknown parts

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a File, which contains text. Now, I have to replace some string with another. For Example I have to replace

```
"[ContactLetterSalutation]"
```

with

```
 "Dear Thomas Kehl".
```

Now, it is possible, that the placeholder `"[ContactLetterSalutation]"` contains somewhere `"=\r\n"` - this could be one, two or more times - for example

```
"[Conta=\r\ntLetterSa=\r\nlutation]".
```

I am searching now a way, that I can also replace this - I don't know where and how many times there will be `"=\r\n"`. The difficult is, that I should not replace all occurrences of `"=\r\n"` in the text. Can someone help me how to do this? Is there perhaps a possibility to do this with RegEx?

Thank you.
Best Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string GetReplacement(Match m) {
    // Get the matched string.
    string x = m.ToString().Replace("=\r\n","");
    return Lookup[x];
}

...
file = Regex.Replace(file, @"\[.*?\]", GetReplacement, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

edit:

RegexOptions.Singleline causes . to match \n

edit2:

While the above should work for small files, I think this question is more interesting for streams where you couldn't get the whole file into a single string. I've come up with this but it probably has bugs:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Chunk(TextReader reader) {
    char[] chars = new char[MaxBufferSize];
    string buffer = "";
    int charsRead;
    while ((charsRead = reader.ReadBlock(chars, 0, MaxBufferSize)) > 0) {
        buffer = buffer + new string(chars,0,charsRead);
        int indexOfOpenBracket;
        if((indexOfOpenBracket = buffer.IndexOf('[')) == -1) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buffer)) yield return buffer;
            buffer = "";
            continue;
        }
        while (indexOfOpenBracket!=-1) {
            string outsideBrackets = buffer.Substring(0, indexOfOpenBracket);
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outsideBrackets)) yield return outsideBrackets;
            buffer = buffer.Substring(indexOfOpenBracket + 1);
            int indexOfCloseBracket = buffer.IndexOf(']');
            if (indexOfCloseBracket != -1) {
                string insideBrackets = buffer.Substring(0, indexOfCloseBracket);
                buffer = buffer.Substring(indexOfCloseBracket + 1);
                yield return DoLookup(insideBrackets);
            } else {
                buffer = '[' + buffer;
                break;
            }
            indexOfOpenBracket = buffer.IndexOf('[');
        }
    }
    yield return buffer;
}
public static void BufferReplace(Stream input, Stream output) {
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(input);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output);
    foreach (var chunk in Chunk(reader)) {
        writer.Write(chunk);
    }
    writer.Flush();
}
```

Comment: This is a code version of Sjoerd's answer; I got ninja'd and didn't pay attention. I'll leave it but mark his as correct.

Comment: Bill's Answer is equivalent but more elegant than mine. just make sure that if you use his regex that your patterns you are looking up have the [ and ] in them or use groups as I described.

Comment: Hi Bill. Thank you. But there is a problem. \r\n is a LineBreak - now your RegEx-Pattern don't find this. What does I have to change, that the RegEx-Pattern will also find Patterns which contains a LineBreak between the [ ]?

Comment: I'd say it's the other way 'round: @Sjoerd merely restated the problem, while you showed how to solve it (the key being to use a MatchEvaluator).  +1 to you.

Answer (score 6):

- Search for anything within brackets, using a regex.
- For every match, remove all =\r\n to find the key.
- Replace the match with the value.

Example:

- You search for `[`*anything*`]`.
- You find `[Conta=\r\ntLetterSa=\r\nlutation]`.
- You use the key `ContatLetterSalutation` to find the correct value.
- You replace `[Conta=\r\ntLetterSa=\r\nlutation]` with that value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with regex. I would not try to make that happen in one pass. I assume that you have an HashTable or other storage where you can lookup the placeholder string to get the text you want to put in its place. Also I am assuming you want to do this from C# code, there is a tool call sed that wil do this from the command line in unix/linux or cygwin underwindows that does it. and it works with regular expressions.

when working out regex expressions I like to use this site: http://regexpal.com/

so first you try and find the pattern for the place holder with the unwanted \r\n in it: "\[([^\]]+)\]" this will find any pattern that starts with a [ has at least one character that is not ] and ends with ].

once you have the list of matches you can work on removing the pattern you do not want before using it for your lookup.

here is a very simple little example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String textFromFile = "some text [re=\r\npla=\r\nme] more [Anoth=\r\ner=\r\n place=\r\n=\r\n=\r\n holder] text";

            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(textFromFile, "\\[([^\\]]+)\\]"))
            {
                String placeHolder = match.Groups[1].Value.Replace("=\r\n", "");
                // *** Do rest of your work here ***.
                System.Console.WriteLine(placeHolder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This program prints out:

```
replaceme
Another place holder
```